# Symfony2 Роли на редактирование отдельных атрибутов сущности

Tags: php, symfony2, безопасность, role

Подскажите есть ли готовое решение позволяющее задать роли на редактирование отдельных атрибутов сущности или груп атрибутов. Сложность заключается в том, что некоторые сущности сохраняются вместе с вложенными, например:

```
PUT /api/users
{
    "name":"Some user",
    "email":"email@mail.com",
    "addresses":[
        {"city":"City1", "street":"Street1"},
        {"city":"City2", "street":"Street2"}
    ]
}
```

Можно ли создать роли `ROLE_UPDATE_USER_NAME`, `ROLE_UPDATE_USER_EMAIL`, `ROLE_UPDATE_ADDRESS_CITY`, `ROLE_UPDATE_ADDRESS_STREET` и производить сохранение только тех атрибутов, на которые есть соответствующее права? Подскажите пожалуйста в каком направлении нужно двигатся...